# How does DisplayString SIZE in MIB files affect the output of snmpget?

Tags: snmp

I have a Cisco switch which SNMP agent returns up to 256 characters long interface descriptions(`ifAlias`). For example here I receive an 100 characters long interface description:

```
$ snmpget -m ./IF-MIB_tmp -M /usr/share/snmp/mibs/ -M
/usr/local/share/snmp/mibs/ -Ov -v 2c -c public switch
IF-MIB::ifAlias.53
STRING: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
$
```

However, DisplayString SIZE in MIB files is 64 characters:

```
$ grep -A 5 -i "^ifalias" ./IF-MIB_tmp /usr/share/snmp/mibs/* /usr/local/shar /snmp/mibs/*
./IF-MIB_tmp:ifAlias   OBJECT-TYPE
./IF-MIB_tmp-    SYNTAX      DisplayString (SIZE(0..64))
./IF-MIB_tmp-    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
./IF-MIB_tmp-    STATUS      current
./IF-MIB_tmp-    DESCRIPTION
./IF-MIB_tmp-            "This object is an 'alias' name for the interface as
--
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/mib-rfc2863a.txt:ifAlias   OBJECT-TYPE
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/mib-rfc2863a.txt-    SYNTAX      DisplayString (SIZE(0..64))
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/mib-rfc2863a.txt-    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/mib-rfc2863a.txt-    STATUS      current
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/mib-rfc2863a.txt-    DESCRIPTION
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/mib-rfc2863a.txt-            "This object is an 'alias' name for the interface as
$
```

I expected that `snmpget` displays the number of characters defined with DisplayString SIZE parameter, e.g first 64 "x" characters. Does DisplayString SIZE affect the output of `snmpget`? If it does, then how? Or is the DISPLAY-HINT parameter the only one which actually changes the output of SNMP GetResponse values?

Answer (score 1):

Information in your client MIB will have no bearing on the value it receives from the server/switch, nor should it. `snmpget` is simply returning what the Cisco switch SNMP agent is giving it. In this case, the MIB is mostly a guideline: Cisco is free to implement it's MIB as it will, as long as Cisco's implementation conforms to the SMIv2 definition of DisplayString, which can be anywhere from 0..255 in length (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2579). This is also the standard for RFC 2863 (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2863).

Comment: On the other hand, DISPLAY-HINT in MIB files actually change the format of returned data for `snmpget`/`snmpwalk` output. Good example is DISPLAY-HINT for PhysAddr. Still, what is the purpose of `DisplayString (SIZE(0..64))`? Does the `DisplayString SIZE` affect anything at all?